# Is S3 (Simple Storage Service) an open source protocol?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Recently I encountered a cloud provider that offers [object storage](https://www.arvancloud.ir/en/products/cloud-storage) (blob storage).

I wanted to try it and to my surprise, their [API documentation](https://www.arvancloud.ir/api/storage/1.1) is all about AWS S3.

Even if you [scroll down](https://www.arvancloud.ir/api/storage/1.1#tag/Bucket/operation/DeleteBucket) and click on class links (like `CreateBucket` link) it takes you to the amazon S3 docs.

Now I tested them both. But when I create a bucket here, I don't see it there. And when I create a bucket in AWS S3 I don't see it here.

So, it seems that this provider uses S3 as an infrastrcuture.

Thus my question is, is S3 an open-source blob provider infrastructure? Or is it propriotary only to Amazon?

Comment: Amazon S3 has become such a popular service that other companies implement the same API so that software can easily move between storage services. Amazon S3 API calls use HTTPS and REST as their "protocol", whereas the API definition defines what information is sent and received.